# Jar Probability Word Problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

2 people are in a competition. Jars are placed in a row and are labelled from left to right 1, 2, 3... A ball is concealed in one of these jars and all jars have the same chance of having the ball inside of them.

Each contestant takes turns to guess which jar the ball is inside of. If one of them guesses the right jar, the anchor will say 'correct', which indicates that the contestant has won. However, if they guess is wrong, the anchor will state 'smaller' or 'bigger' (referring to the numbers) to show the direction the ball is hidden. The contestants always obey the anchor's directions. For example, if ten jars are presented (labelled one to ten) and the ball is concealed in jar seven, the contest may go like the following (follow the link to see the example):

[image: contest_sequence_example]

A contest has jars labelled one up to four. Why is it that regardless of which jar Person A picks on his first go, Person B has a method for guaranteeing her probability of victory as 1/2. Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If person A guesses right on the first try, then person B has probability $0$ of winning.   Please clarify what you mean by saying regardless of which jar person A picks on his first go, person B has a method for guaranteeing her probability of victory as $1/2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - i assume the OP meant B has a strategy, i.e. a comprehensive plan covering all scenarios, so that no matter what A does, B's chance of winning (averaged over many trials) is at least 1/2.  e.g. to combat what you observed, B's strategy must be s.t., conditioned on A not winning right away, B's winning prob must be at least 2/3 (because ${2 \over 3} (1 - {1 \over 4}) = {1 \over 2}$).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The question is asking for a comprehensive strategy for B, i.e. a recipe for what to do in all cases when B has a choice.  In this simple game there are only 2 situations where B even has to choose (the rest are equivalent by symmetry):

- If A picks 1 and does not win right away, what should B pick?  There are 3 choices: 2, 3, or 4.
- If A picks 2 and does not win right away, and if the anchor says "bigger", then what should B pick?  There are 2 choices: 3 or 4.

So a strategy for B is simply a pair $(s,t)$ where $s\in \{2, 3, 4\}$ and $t \in \{3, 4\}$.  There are 6 strategies, and each can be analyzed to find B's overall probability of winning (if using that strategy).  If you do this carefully you will find that some of them indeed guarantees 1/2 chance of winning.

Comment: This is a nice hint.

Comment: Thank you for the hint; I think I have an answer now. 

So if A picks '2' on the first go, there is a 1/4 chance of A winning. But if A loses and the anchor says 'lower', then B will have a 1/1 chance of winning as only '1' is left. If the anchor says higher, then B will have a 1/2 chance of winning as there are two options ('3' and '4') left.

If A picks 1, there is a 1/4 chance of them winning. But if A loses, then the answer will obviously be higher, leaving three options (2, 3, and 4). B will have to then pick 2 or 4 to have a 1/2 chance of winning. Is this explanation correct?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hint; I think I have an answer now.

So if A picks '2' on the first go, there is a 1/4 chance of A winning. But if A loses and the anchor says 'lower', then B will have a 1/1 chance of winning as only '1' is left. If the anchor says higher, then B will have a 1/2 chance of winning as there are two options ('3' and '4') left.

If A first picks 1, there is a 1/4 chance of them winning. But if A loses, then the answer will obviously be higher, leaving three options (2, 3, and 4). B will have to then pick 2 or 4 to have a 1/2 chance of winning. Is this explanation correct?

Comment: in each case, you need to show that the OVERALL chance of winning is 1/2 (or more).  if you just say "if A didnt win then B has 1/2 chance" that is not good enough, IMHO.

Comment: I don't understand. How would I show this?

Comment: you have the right strategy, which is "if A picks 1 (and doesnt win) then i pick 2.  if A picks 2 (and doesnt win) and if the anchor says bigger then i pick 3."  now calculate the overall chance of winning if A picks 1.  also calculate the overall chance of winning if A picks 2.  you should find that in both cases, B's chance is 1/2.